# Go to definition in visual studio code does not work

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup visual studio code for a nodejs project following https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

I created a jsconfig.json file in my root folder with the contents

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5", //tried ES6 as well
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

> This file tells VS Code you are writing ES5 compliant code and the module system you want to use is the commonjs framework. With these options set, you can start to write code that references modules in other files. For example, in app.js we require the ./routes/index module, which exports an Express.Router class. If you bring up IntelliSense on routes, you can see the shape of the Router class.

Although it doesn't seem to work with vscode 0.9.1. I don't get intellisense on my own modules. Go to definition doesn't work either.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs#_great-code-editing-experiences

Is there a way to get go to definition working?

Comment: On a side note: did you consider using Typescript?

Comment: It is an open source project written in javascript https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB

Comment: I can't get go to definition to work either, i'm trying with c# files/project

Comment: I'm using 0.10.6, go to definition seems to work only for stuff defined with `var` or `function`. Doesn't work for global things, doesn't work for anything declared with `this.`. Same for Intellisense I think.

Comment: Did you have installed the [typings](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs#_intellisense-and-typings) referring to the API you are using?

Comment: it works when you install typings for modules you are using. it was working for me on some old version... now we have vs 1.6.1 you should try installing typing

Comment: I made a simple repo to show what I am talking about. https://github.com/barisusakli/vs-code-intellisense-test, it doesn't work for simple user modules depending on how you write your module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR; if you set your variables/functions directly on the `exports` object it seems to work.

---

After trying different ways to write modules I found out it works if you write your module in a certain way. Here is an example that works.

```
exports.myFunction = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

Now if you import this module from another file you will get intellisense and go to definition will work. However if you write your module like this or any other variation it will not work.

```
var myModule = {};
myModule.myFunction = function (a,b) {
    return a + b;
};
exports = myModule;
```

Filed an issue on the vscode repository.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15004#issuecomment-258980327

I will update my answer if this changes.

Comment: I am having the same problem almost three and a half years later. Would you know if there have been any developments in this regard?

Comment: I think it was somewhat improved in the later versions but still not 100%, alot of similar issues are linked in this thread https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10868

Comment: Any chances this has been fixed?

Comment: foo = function(){...} has no definition in VSC but  function foo(){} does

Comment: Yes, this is painful. I use the workaround: double click to select the word, and search by Cmd+Shift+F, and manually go to the file with the definition

Comment: Any solution for this? I am dealing with the same issue. Depending on the code style VSC go to definition will work or does not. Seems crazy! Until a solution comes I will be using Jetbrains.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions work give this one a try for **mac** users.

Sometime VSC caches the settings and how much you try it will behave the same way so try resetting VSC.

```
rm -rfv "$HOME/.vscode"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState"
```

Restart VSC - `code .` (Should start from scratch)

Also remove .vscode/ `rm -rf .vscode/`