# how to using vscode JavaScript's 'go to definition' cross files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there anyway to use 'go to definition' find one function definition in other file?
Two files are in the same folder/own the same parent folder.

I know the html holds all .js files, but I can't find any way in Google.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Maybe if you're using TypeScript. I don't think the tools that rely on static analysis work in JavaScript's dynamic world.

Comment: Although, [here's an article](https://mdcox.net/posts/static-checking-with-vscode-jsdoc.html) about how to get Intellisense working in VSCode with JS, maybe if you set up a `jsconfig.json` file it might work?

Comment: Also it looks like your question might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194157/go-to-definition-in-visual-studio-code-does-not-work).

Comment: @bmceldowney I am new to JavaScript, using vscode, working with a JavaScript lib in github, I find 'go to definition' not work when enconter cross file definition.

Comment: Take a look at the links in my other comments, they may help you out.

Comment: @bmceldowney github.com/ivmartel/dwv this lib can't use your way to navigate definition cross files, any suggestion?

Answer (score 43):

**You must enable "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" extension in VS Code. It could be disabled by ESLint extension.**

[image]

Comment: Go to your extensions and search `@builtin typescript` to find the extension above.

Comment: Finally! Thank you.

Comment: Try disable TypeScript Language Basics

Comment: I tried and this solution just works

Answer (score 13):

You need to create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) file at the root of your project.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

This file tells VS Code to treat all `*.js` files in the workspace as part of the same project. However it will not enable intellisense between javascript in `<script>` blocks and regular js files.

If this is still not working, try enabling `checkJS` in your js files to track down what is going wrong: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking-and-quick-fixes-for-javascript-files

Answer (score 3):

May be i am late in the show but even after trying all of the above answers i was facing the same issue but soon while editing the settings.json (Same as Settings which comes when we do "Ctrl + ," on VSCode) I realized that there was a setting "editor.multiCursorModifier" set as "ctrlCmd" as shown in the snapshot which when i commented resolved my problem. So this may be considered as a solution for the issue posted.

[image: User Settings]

Answer (score 2):

This may be overkill, but it seemed to work for me (on a Mac):

```
rm -rfv "$HOME/.vscode"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode"
rm -rfv "$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState"
```

Restart VSC -  `code .` (Should start from scratch)

Also remove .vscode/ `rm -rf .vscode/`

Comment: Thank you for this. I had totally screwed up typescript within VSCode and this fixed it with a reinstall

Comment: This was indeed a drastic solution. But it also worked for me (on a Mac).